# 'There was an error reading IIS configuration schema from 'C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\' Visual Studio 2010 Windows 8 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2010, iis, web-development

I have a users who is attempting to deploy a web service through Visual Studio 2010 on a windows 8 64-bit laptop but is getting an error.

When the users tries to deploy through visual studio he receives the error message - 'There was an error reading IIS configuration schema from 'C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\'

He is a local admin on the machine, I have turned off User Account Control (UAC) and disabled 'User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin approval mode.' Security option.

Any help or advice on this would be much appreciated as I am really not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the following for the comment below :-

- Run your Visual studio as administrator and try again.

***Comment***

Please refer to the following link :- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2735834

This is the known issues for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on a Windows 8-based computer .

**Symptoms**

When you try to publish a website or a Web application to `http://localhost` by using Internet Information Services (IIS) settings in Visual Studio 2010 on a computer that is running Windows 8, you receive an error message that resembles the following:

```
There was an error reading IIS configuration schema from "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\"
```

**Workaround**

To work around this issue, use one of the following methods:

- Use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 to publish the website or the Web application.
- Use the latest Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (Visual Studio 2010 SP1) to publish the website or the Web application. Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET provides an updated Web publish experience, and will not cause this problem. The following file is available for download from the Microsoft Download Center:
  [Download the Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2010 SP1) package now](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=254269).

Answer (score 2):

I had accidentally installed Web Deploy 2.0 and I got this error when trying to deploy my webapp. After I installed the latest, Web Deploy 3.6, from [the IIS extensions site](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy), the error disappeared on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the pain of this issue and I discovered that by default, Windows 10 disables the Administrator account. As a result, any service impersonating this account fails to access the priviledged folder where settings are stored.

Once enabled, run the deployment, and it works. I had to login as Administrator, then run deployment. It worked for me. I also installed Web Deploy 3.6, from the IIS extensions site, as advised above.

[image]